# How do I find the distance between object A and B (same size) by comparing perceived size. Better description in details.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

So I have this picture, with 2 objects. They are both the same size. Object B appears as size 200 pixels (lets say this is the actual size if that helps). Object A appears as size 100 pixels. They are both 400 pixels apart. How do I find how far behind object B object A is (in pixels). [image: I made a basic diagram of the scenario here.]

Thanks in advance! :D

Comment: Wouldn't that depend on the FOV?

Comment: I also don't understand how [tag:real-analysis] and [tag:real-algebraic-geometry] are relevant, please refrain from using tags which aren't relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are both the same size, A is twice as far away from you as B.  But we have no way to know how far that is.

Comment: Alright, I'll try finding another approach to my problem then. Thanks for the response!